# Movieclip is not looping

Tags: createjs, movieclip, animate-cc

Since yesterday I have an issue with my Animate cc (HTML5 Canvas). My movieclips sometimes is not looping. Here the link on fla file with example:

[Not Loop (Google Drive)](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1T_ogKZYrRfR-1YoGS6KOsUNqG2iWUFFN)

There is movieclip "arrows" that plays only once.

And here the same movieclip is looped:

[Loop (Google Drive)](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1aYLYK6fH9kUyZ1-6AE93xWY0fBeO7UWL)

UPDATE1:
When i publish my project, in generated js file i got this lines adding my movieclip to the library:

```
(lib.arrows = function(mode,startPosition,loop) {  
if (loop == null) { loop = false; } this.initialize(mode,startPosition,loop,{});
```

And i understand that this part don't let looping a movieclip:

```
if (loop == null) { loop = false; }
```

But what i dont understand, is why this part sometimes is added and sometimes not. It's so strange. It is added with no reason on my opinion, because i create my movieclips as usual.

Help me please to understand what's the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was find an answer. Maybe it's a bug. But when i inside a movieclip in my workspace and publish a project (with checkbox "Loop timeline" not checked), i got this movieclip is not looping. When i going next level up to the Scene and then publish a project (with checkbox "Loop timeline" not checked), it's ok, movieclip is looping.

Answer (score 0):

When publishing the project you need to check 'Loop Timeline' in the 'Publish Settings' (Ctrl+Shift+F12), it's affects not only main timeline, but Movieclips too.
[image]

Comment: Thank you for answer. But as i know, movieclips independent from the main timeline. And when "Loop timeline" checkbox is not checked, movieclips are still loops. I just checked it in my Animate CC to make sure.